# debugging recursive functions

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

I was stepping through this code below and the part that I do not understand is how "Leaving" n value becomes 2,5 and 10. I understand the first part of recursive calls till n==0, and return takes the control to move to the else part and print (0%2). Shouldn't the program halt after that?

```
void fun2(int n){
    System.out.println("Entering"+n);
    if(n==0)
        return;
   else{
        fun2(n/2);
        System.out.print("Leaving"+n+"---->");       
        System.out.println(n%2);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
      Entering5
      Entering2
      Entering1
      Entering0
      Leaving1---->1
      Leaving2---->0
      Leaving5---->1
      Leaving10---->0
```

Comment: It's one way to debug.  Another way is to simply step through line-by-line in a debugger.

Comment: Also, how does the behaviour of this code differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: I have no idea of how leaving gets the values of "n" of entering. I've hardly had to use recursion so tracing this seems a fairly confusing task. Could you explain? This is not my code. I just added the prints

Comment: A recursive function call is no different to any other function call.  If `funcA()` calls `funcB()`, the values in the scope of `funcA()` are retained until `funcB()` returns.  Exactly the same occurs in a recursive call situation.

Comment: Im sorry I still dont seem to get it. This part of the output is what is confusing.

The return causing the control to enter the else part with n=1 and printing seems to be all I can trace to. After that the control again returns the print statements of the else part causing to print this 
Leaving2---->0
Leaving5---->1
Leaving10---->0

Why does this happen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe that you have an error in your output.  When I run the above code by calling `fun2()` with a value of 5, I get all of the output that you've indicated *except the line `Leaving10---->0`*.  Are you sure that this is in the output of the `fun2()` function or perhaps an artifact from the code location where you call `fun2()`?  Perhaps you're calling the `fun2()` function with a value of 10, and left off the first first line of output `Entering10`?

This function works by calculating the value of each binary digit. This is done using the % operator, known as the modulo operator (also known as the remainder operator) in the final line of the else block: `System.out.println(n%2);`

```
101 = (1*2^2) + (0*2^1) + (1*2^0) = 4 + 0 + 1 = 5
```

Each iteration calculates the next lower power of 2 because it's called with `n/2`.  Bear in mind that you're dealing with integer division here, so there is no remainder.  1/2 = 0, not 0.5.  However, the integer modulus function will work just fine, so 1%2 = 1 (1 divided by 2 = 0 with a remainder of 1).

Here's a detailed look at each recursion level of the method:

1. n = 5, n/2 = 2, fun2(2), n%2 = 1
2. n = 2, n/2 = 1, fun2(1), n%2 = 0
3. n = 1, n/2 = 0, fun2(0), n%2 = 1
4. n = 0, method returns

When you put the individual console output together, you get 101, which is binary for 5.

If you were to have called `fun2()` with a parameter value of 10, you would have seen the output `1010`:

```
1010 = (1*2^3) + (0*2^2) + (1*2^1) + (0*2^0) = 8 + 0 + 2 + 0 = 10
```